# How to achieve 8bit madd using SSE2

Tags: c++, video, sse, simd, sse2

Reading from the official Intel C++ Intrinsic Reference,

**SSE 2** has the following command

```
__m128i _mm_madd_epi16(__m128i a, __m128i b)
```

*Multiplies the 8 signed 16-bit integers from a by the 8 signed 16-bit integers from b.
Adds the signed 32-bit integer results pairwise and packs the 4 signed 32-bit integer
results.*

while **SSE 3** has

```
__m128i _mm_maddubs_epi16 (__m128i a, __m128i b)
```

*Multiply signed and unsigned bytes, add horizontal pair of signed words, pack
saturated signed words.*

Since Im working with 8bit pixels and I must only use SSE 2(old architecture is the target) I need an **8bit madd** instruction.
How would I proceed with that?

Comment: set compiler flags, include header, call function while taking care of the alignment :)

Comment: Use punpckhbw and punpcklbw to expand 8-bit unsigned data to 16-bit and use _mm_madd_epi16.

Comment: @user874877 By the way `__m128i _mm_maddubs_epi16 (__m128i a, __m128i b)` intrinsic is in **SSSE3**, not in **SSE3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this works - I don't have a compiler here. But even if I missed something, you should get the overall idea.

EDIT: Thanks to @Peter Cordes for pointing out that `_mm_setzero_si128` should better be used directly.

```
inline __m128i _mm_madd_epi8_SSE2(const __m128i & a, const __m128i & b)
{
    // a = 0x00 0x01 0xFE 0x04 ...
    // b = 0x00 0x02 0x80 0x84 ...

    // To extend signed 8-bit value, MSB has to be set to 0xFF
    __m128i sign_mask_a  = _mm_cmplt_epi8(a, _mm_setzero_si128());
    __m128i sign_mask_b  = _mm_cmplt_epi8(b, _mm_setzero_si128());

    // sign_mask_a = 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0x00 ...
    // sign_mask_b = 0x00 0x00 0xFF 0xFF ...

    // Unpack positives with 0x00, negatives with 0xFF
    __m128i a_epi16_l    = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(a, sign_mask_a);
    __m128i a_epi16_h    = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(a, sign_mask_a);
    __m128i b_epi16_l    = _mm_unpacklo_epi8(b, sign_mask_b);
    __m128i b_epi16_h    = _mm_unpackhi_epi8(b, sign_mask_b);

    // Here - valid 16-bit signed integers corresponding to the 8-bit input
    // a_epi16_l = 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0xFE 0xFF 0x04 0x00 ... 

    // Get the a[i] * b[i] + a[i+1] * b[i+1] for both low and high parts
    __m128i madd_epi32_l = _mm_madd_epi16(a_epi16_l, b_epi16_l);
    __m128i madd_epi32_h = _mm_madd_epi16(a_epi16_h, b_epi16_h);

    // Now go back from 32-bit values to 16-bit values & signed saturate
    return _mm_packs_epi16(madd_epi32_l, madd_epi32_h);
}
```

Comment: For integer compares, there's only `cmpeq` and `cmpgt` (until AVX512 gives us an integer compare instruction that takes an immediate byte to choose the predicate, like `cmpps`).  We can work around it with `_mm_cmpgt_epi8(_mm_setzero_si128(), a)` to produce the upper halves for sign-extension.

Comment: Also, don't use `static ... = _mm_setzero_si128();`  For gcc, `_mm_setzero` isn't really a compile-time constant, so you'll get code that zeros some memory at run-time.  Plus, you don't want to load all-zeros from memory anyway; `pxor xmm1,xmm1` is cheaper than a load.  Just use `_mm_setzero_si128()` directly, or assign it to a non-static `const __m128i` local variable.  Same for `_mm_set_epi8(some data)`: just let the compiler worry about managing constants.

Comment: Thanks for making me look into the `_mm_setzero_si128` instruction. Indeed, it's a `pxor` with latency 1 and throughput 0.33. Cannot agree on `_mm_cmplt_epi8` [availability](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_cmplt_epi8&techs=SSE2) though: Although effectively both `_mm_cmplt_epi8` and `_mm_cmpgt_epi8` indeed resort to the same `pcmpgtb` instruction, I don't see any reason why you can't use either of those.

Comment: OP says he is working with "8 bit pixels", which would presumably be unsigned. Hence you should just be able to do an unsigned unpack (i.e. just interleave with 0 in the high byte).

Comment: For RGB color model that would be true, but for Y'CbCr there are two schemes for energy mapping: Unsigned Y´, Two's Complement Cb, Cr and Unsigned Y´, Offset Binary Cb, Cr, which use signed and unsigned data types correspondingly. Since OP mentioned only `epi16` routines in his post, I assumed the `madd` he needs shall be `epi8`, not `epu8`.

Comment: @kikobyte: oh, I never noticed there were `cmplt` intrinsics.  There's nothing wrong with it, I just thought it was an error since neither of us had tried compiling it :P.  I usually think about what asm I want the compiler to generate, and work backwards from that to intrinsics, so I normally look at the asm instruction reference manual, not the intrinsics guide.

Comment: And re: xor-zeroing: `pxor same,same` is a [zeroing idiom recognized by the CPU](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/which-is-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and/33668295#33668295), so it doesn't really have a meaningful latency: it's always the start of a new dependency chain.  And on Intel SnB-family CPUs, it doesn't even take an execution unit, so it has one per 0.25 cycle throughput.  (It's handled in the register-rename stage, by renaming to a physical zeroed register).

Comment: @Peter Cordes Actually, complier should know that zeroing a register with pxor is much easier than loading it. It is not necessary to write it into the same line.

Comment: Yes, hopefully a compiler would optimize away the `static const __m128i zero = _mm_setzero_si128();`, but it's easier and better not to tempt the compiler to do it wrong.  It's not bad to define a `const __m128i zero= ...`, but the problem is making it `static`.  You *don't* want static, that implies static storage.